# Django + JQuery Ajax post

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I have read all on the theme but I can't understand what's wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("tweet.py", {
        lat : searchResult._point.__lat,
        lng : searchResult._point.__lng,
        text : searchResult.text
    },  function(data) {
           alert(data);
        });
    });
```

The handler's code:

```
import django

def iEventAjax(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

The alert message is

```
"import django
def iEventAjax(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse("ok")
"
```

instead of "ok"

what's wrong?

Comment: Surely you have to post to a URL on your server, not to a file.

Comment: what should i write instead?  $.post("/", {  ?

Comment: which url? i have two file in the project directory, the file that contains js and html from where i send post and file tweet.py

Comment: Well you presumably know how to write URLconfs in Django. One of the URLs in that URLconf is (also presumably) connected to your "handler" function. So that's the URL you want to be posting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add in your urls.py an url like

```
(r'^ajaxrequest$', 'app.views.iEventAjax')
```

and then change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("/ajaxrequest", {
        lat : searchResult._point.__lat,
        lng : searchResult._point.__lng,
        text : searchResult.text
    },  function(data) {
           alert(data);
        });
    });
```

in your views.py of your app

```
def iEventAjax(request):
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```